# How to link python program with twisted python?

Tags: python

I have to do a program of multiclient chat server in python using twisted python. I don't know, how to link it with that library. Can anybody tell the answer, please?

Is there a need to implement separate client and server programs for multiclient chat server as in socket programming in C?

Comment: I would suggest that you first learn Python, since there is no such thing as "linking" when using Python packages (as libraries are called in Python.)

Comment: I have some knowledge in python. I installed the twisted python library. But I don't know how to link it with program.. like., python a.py -lib

Comment: You don't "link" python packages, you "import" them. May I suggest the [Python module tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)?

Comment: No. Thank you. I imported it. just did the echoserver program. got it. thank you Joachim Pileborg

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: seems you should make that an answer

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by [Chris Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497043/chris-morgan), I add this as an answer.

You don't "link" python packages, you "import" them. May I suggest the [Python module](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) tutorial?